# iCloud: Restore file which has been deleted a few days prior. How long possible?

Tags: icloud, restore

Let's say I have deleted a file accidently a few days ago and I have discovered my mistake right now.

- Is it possible to restore this file, when it was inside of the iCloud-folders?

In case a restore is possible:

- How long is a file-restoration possible, starting from the day of deletion on backwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Restore file which has been deleted a few days prior. How long possible?

30 days.

> Is it possible to restore this file, when it was inside of the iCloud-folders?

Yes.

> - How long is a file-restoration possible, starting from a specific day on backwards?

30 days.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Mac computers only:

If you have a Time Machine backup, and your settings include your iCloud folder (usually located at `~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs`), then you can restore your file as long as there is a backup with that file.

This means that theoretically, it would be limitless, but in practise, just until the disk fills up with backups